# Coin Toss Game - Probability of H when unequal number of coins tossed

Tags: probability, gambling

Two gamblers are playing coin toss game: Gambler A has (n+1) coins and B has n coins. What is the probability that A will have more heads than B if both flip all their coins.

Not sure how to go about solving it. Any ideas? What if A has (n+2) coins.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A probability theory question about independent coin tosses by two players](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662958/a-probability-theory-question-about-independent-coin-tosses-by-two-players)

Comment: Hint: After $A$ has tossed $n$ of her coins, and $B$ has tossed all of hers, either (i) $A$ is leading or (ii) $B$ is leading or (iii) they are tied. Note that (i) and (ii) are equally likely.

Comment: @lulu: This one has the additional $A$ has $n+2$ coins question.

Comment: @AndréNicolas  Ah, missed that.  Thanks.  Doubt that case is easy...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a fair coin.

Let $X$ be the count of successes in the first $n$ flips by A, $Y$ the indicator that the last flip by A is also a success, and $Z$ the count of successes in $n$ flips by B.

Because $Y$ is independent of $X$ and $Z$, then:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X+Y>Z) ~=&~ \mathsf P(Y=1)\,\mathsf P(X\geq Z)+\mathsf P(Y=0)\,\mathsf P(X>Z)\\ = &~ \tfrac 12(\mathsf P(X=Z)+2~\mathsf P(X>Z)) \end{align}$$

Note by symmetry that $\mathsf P(X>Z) = \mathsf P(Z>X)$ and so ...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are $n+1$ coins for Gambler A and $n$ coins for Gambler B.

The possibilities for Gambler B are $2^n$ and the possibilities for Gambler A are $2^{n+1}$ or $2^n \cdot 2$. There are twice as many possibilities and half of them in which there is an additional heads. Simply put Gambler A has a $50\%$ chance of having strictly more head flips.

But the real insights come when you generalize the problem to say that Gambler B has $n$ coins and flips $k$ heads. What are the chances that Gambler A flips more than $k$ heads given they have $n + m$ coins.

Well the chance, $p$, that someone flips a given number of heads or more than a given number of heads is given by the [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) which can be used to show that the probability of Gambler A achieving at least more heads than Gambler B is given by the following equation:

$\begin{align*} p =\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left({n \choose k} \cdot 0.5^k \cdot 0.5^{n-k} \cdot \sum_{j=k+1}^{n+m} \left( {n+m \choose j} \cdot 0.5^j \cdot 0.5^{n+m-j}\right)\right)
\end{align*}$

I'll add more when I can. But in the mean time you may be able to see that $p$ remains $0.5$ no matter how large $n$ becomes as long as $m$ is $1$.

However if $m$ is $2$ the situation becomes exceedingly more complicated because the answer is not constant. Here are the first few cases:

- $n$ is $1$ then $p$ is $0.6875$.
- $n$ is $2$ then $p$ is $0.65625$.
- $n$ is $3$ then $p$ is about $0.63671$.
- $n$ is $1000$ then $p$ is about $0.50891$.

Gambler A loses his comparative advantage the more coins that are tossed for both Gamblers. But Gambler A will always maintain the advantage and has quite a heavy advantage when few coins are tossed.

When Gambler A has one extra coin he may as well just toss one coin. When Gambler A has more than one extra coins, I don't see a way to simplify things here (which doesn't mean that it doesn't exist).

Comment: how about the case when m>1, say m=2

Comment: @Gerry When $m=2$ the highest $p$ will be is when $n=1$, which is $0.6875$. As $n$ increases the relative advantage of Gambler A decreases and $p$ approaches $0.5$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please elaborate on how you arrived at expression for p in your solution.

Comment: @Gerry The largest summation, that is $\sum_{k=0}^{n}$ covers all cases of Gambler B flipping $k$ heads from 0 heads to $n$ heads. The second part comes from the binomial distribution and is the probability that Gambler B flips exactly $k$ heads. That is multiplied by the chance that Gambler A flips $k$ or more heads ($k+1$ to $n+m$ heads). So it is a summation of binomial distributions so to speak. The summation essentially adds the chance of Gambler A flipping more than $k$ heads for each possible number of heads that can be flipped for Gambler B. Does that make it clear?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, we observe that the probability of A getting more heads than B is symmetrical to the probability of A getting more tails than B. This symmetry arises from the fact that the coin flips are independent events, and there is no inherent bias towards heads or tails.

Now, when A has one more coin than B (n+1 coins for A and n coins for B), A can either have more heads than B or more tails than B, but not both. This is because the total number of coin flips is fixed, and each coin can only result in either a head or a tail.

Combining these two observations, we conclude that the probability of A obtaining more heads than B is equal to the probability of A obtaining more tails than B, and since these are the only two possible outcomes, each with an equal chance, the overall probability is 1/2 or 50%. This is a result of the symmetry in the setup, highlighting that, under these conditions, A is equally likely to get more heads than B as it is to get more tails than B.