# Two sets of coin flips

Tags: probability

Below is a problem that I did. I have reason to believe that the correct answer is $\frac{1}{2}$. Please check my work and find any and all errors.
Thanks,
Bob

Problem:
Suppose person 1 flips a fair coin $5$ times and that person 2 flips a fair cont $4$ times. What is the
probability that person 1 got more heads than person 2.
Answer:
Let $p_1(x)$ be the probability that person 1 got $x$ heads. Let $p_2(x)$ be the probability that person 2 got $x$ heads. Let $p$ be the probability we seek.
\begin{align*}
P_1(0) &= \frac{1}{32} \\
P_1(1) &= \frac{5}{32} \\
P_1(2) &= \frac{5}{16} \\
P_1(3) &= \frac{5}{16} \\
P_1(4) &= \frac{5}{32} \\
P_1(5) &= \frac{1}{32} \\
%
P_2(0) &= \frac{1}{16} \\
P_2(1) &= \frac{1}{4} \\
P_2(2) &= \frac{3}{8} \\
P_2(3) &= \frac{1}{4} \\
P_2(4) &= \frac{1}{16} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
p &=  p_1(1) \left( p_2(0) \right) + p_1(2)\left( p_2(0) + p_2(1) \right) + \\
  & p_1(3) \left(  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) \right) + \\
  & p_1(4) (  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) + p_2(3) ) + p_1(5) \\
%
p_1(1) \left( p_2(0) \right) &= \frac{5}{32} \left( \frac{1}{16} \right) = \frac{5}{512} \\
p &=  \frac{5}{512} + p_1(2)\left( p_2(0) + p_2(1) \right) + \\
 &p_1(3) \left(  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) \right) + \\
    &p_1(4) (  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) + p_2(3) ) + p_1(5) \\
p_1(2)\left( p_2(0) + p_2(1) \right) &= \frac{5}{32} \left( \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{4} \right) \\
p_1(2)\left( p_2(0) + p_2(1) \right) &= \frac{5}{32} \left( \frac{5}{16} \right) = \frac{25}{512} \\
p &=  \frac{5}{512} + \frac{25}{512} + p_1(3) \\
   & \left(  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) \right) + p_1(4) (  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) + p_2(3) ) + p_1(5) \\
p &= \frac{30}{512} + \\
  & p_1(3) \left(  \frac{1}{16} +  \frac{1}{4}  + \frac{3}{8}  \right) + p_1(4) (  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) + p_2(3) ) + p_1(5) \\
p &= \frac{30}{512} + p_1(3) \left(  \frac{11}{16} \right) +  \frac{5}{32}  \left(   \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{4} + p_2(2) + p_2(3) \right) + p_1(5) \\
p &= \frac{30}{512} + \frac{5}{16} \left(  \frac{11}{16} \right) +  \frac{5}{32}  \left(   \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{8}  + \frac{1}{4} \right) + \frac{1}{32} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
p &= \frac{30}{512} + \frac{55}{256} +  \frac{5}{32}  \left(   \frac{15}{16} \right) + \frac{1}{32} \\
p &= \frac{140}{512} +  \frac{5}{32}  \left(   \frac{15}{16} \right) + \frac{1}{32} \\
p &= \frac{140}{512} +  \frac{75}{512}  + \frac{16}{512} \\
p &=  \frac{231}{512} \\
\end{align*}

I am hoping that somebody can tell me where I went wrong above.

Based upon the comments I got from the group, here is the correct solution:

Answer:
\newline
Let $p_1(x)$ be the probability that person 1 got $x$ heads. Let $p_2(x)$ be the probability that person 2 got $x$ heads. Let $p$ be the probability we seek.
\begin{align*}
P_1(0) &= \frac{1}{32} \\
P_1(1) &= \frac{5}{32} \\
P_1(2) &= \frac{5}{16} \\
P_1(3) &= \frac{5}{16} \\
P_1(4) &= \frac{5}{32} \\
P_1(5) &= \frac{1}{32} \\
%
P_2(0) &= \frac{1}{16} \\
P_2(1) &= \frac{1}{4} \\
P_2(2) &= \frac{3}{8} \\
P_2(3) &= \frac{1}{4} \\
P_2(4) &= \frac{1}{16} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
p &=  p_1(1) \left( p_2(0) \right) + p_1(2)\left( p_2(0) + p_2(1) \right) + \\
  & p_1(3) \left(  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) \right) + p_1(4) (  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) + p_2(3) ) + p_1(5) \\
%
p_1(1) \left( p_2(0) \right) &= \frac{5}{32} \left( \frac{1}{16} \right) = \frac{5}{512} \\
p &=  \frac{5}{512} + p_1(2)\left( p_2(0) + p_2(1) \right) + \\
 &p_1(3) \left(  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) \right) + p_1(4) (  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) + p_2(3) ) + p_1(5) \\
p_1(2)\left( p_2(0) + p_2(1) \right) &= \frac{5}{16} \left( \frac{1}{16} + \frac{1}{4} \right) \\
p_1(2)\left( p_2(0) + p_2(1) \right) &= \frac{5}{16} \left( \frac{5}{16} \right) = \frac{25}{256} \\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
p &=  \frac{5}{512} + \frac{25}{256} + p_1(3) \left(  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) \right) + p_1(4) (  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) + p_2(3) ) + p_1(5) \\
p &= \frac{55}{512} + \frac{5}{16} \left(  \frac{1}{16} +  \frac{1}{4}  + \frac{3}{8}  \right) + p_1(4) (  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) + p_2(3) ) + p_1(5) \\
p &= \frac{55}{512} + \frac{5}{16} \left(  \frac{11}{16} \right) + p_1(4) (  p_2(0) + p_2(1) + p_2(2) + p_2(3) ) + p_1(5) \\
p &= \frac{55}{512} + \frac{55}{256} + \frac{5}{32} \left(  \frac{1}{16}  + \frac{1}{4} \right) + p_2(2) + p_2(3) ) + p_1(5) \\
p &= \frac{165}{512} + \frac{5}{32} \left(  \frac{5}{16} + p_2(2) + p_2(3) \right) + p_1(5) \\
p &= \frac{165}{512} + \frac{5}{32} \left(  \frac{5}{16} + \frac{3}{8}  +  \frac{1}{4}  \right) + \frac{1}{32} \\
p &= \frac{165}{512} + \frac{5}{32} \left(  \frac{11}{16}  +  \frac{1}{4}  \right) + \frac{1}{32} \\
p &= \frac{165}{512} + \frac{75}{512}  + \frac{1}{32} = \frac{256}{512} \\
p &= \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{align*}

Comment: This is true more generally.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1662958/a-probability-theory-question-about-independent-coin-tosses-by-two-players)

Comment: @lulu I was thinking that the general answer was $\frac{1}{2}$. I am now hoping somebody will tell me where I went wrong above. I am thinking it is an error in arithmetic.

Comment: Well, that certainly seems likely...it looks like a fairly error prone computation.  I don't see anything conceptually wrong with it.

Comment: I just did the same computation on a spreadsheet and got $.5$ so there's just an arithmetic slip up somewhere.

Comment: You have written $$P_1(2)(P_2(0)+P_2(1))=\frac{5}{\color{red}{32}}\left(\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{4}\right)$$ fixing the $32$ to $16$ yields correct computation.